# ViewPager2 as gridview calendar application

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am building a Calendar app and I want it to be like Google Calendar. As I was informed Google Calendar uses ViewPager2. The problem is that I made my adapter and everything I need to populate my Calendar, and I don't know how to implement it to my ViewPager to show it as a total of ArrayList month per month. Currently it shows me only day per day. I think I have to populate it as an ArrayList but I don't know how.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.calendarcapital;

import static com.example.calendarcapital.CalendarUtils.daysInMonthArray;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements CalendarAdapter.OnItemListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ViewPager2Adapter viewPager2Adapter = new ViewPager2Adapter(daysInMonthArray(),this::onItemClick,MainActivity2.this);

        viewPager2.setAdapter(viewPager2Adapter);
        
        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            // This method is triggered when there is any scrolling activity for the current page
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            // triggered when you select a new page
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
            }

            // triggered when there is
            // scroll state will be changed
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, LocalDate date) {


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ViewPager2Adapter**

```
package com.example.calendarcapital;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewPager2Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPager2Adapter.ViewHolder> {



    private final ArrayList<LocalDate> days;
    private final ArrayList<Date> daysForRepeat;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private final OnItemListener onItemListener;
    private MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    static int numEvents;
    static  int numRepeatingEvents;
    Context context;

    // Constructor of our ViewPager2Adapter class
    public ViewPager2Adapter(ArrayList<LocalDate> days, OnItemListener onItemListener, Context context) {
        this.days = days;
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
        this.myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        this.context = context;
        this.daysForRepeat = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // This method returns our layout
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_cell, parent, false);
        LinearLayout test = view.findViewById(R.id.LinCell);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = test.getLayoutParams();

        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);


        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);



        if (days.size() > 15) //month view
        {
//            layoutParams.height = (int) (parent.getHeight() * 0.166666666);
            layoutParams.height = (int) (test.getHeight() * 0.2);

        } else // week view
            layoutParams.height = (int) test.getHeight();



        return new ViewHolder(view, onItemListener, days);
    }

    // This method binds the screen with the view
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllEvents();
        holder.eventDayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventRepeatText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventRepeatText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        final LocalDate date = days.get(position);

        for (LocalDate day : days) {
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                calendar1.set(day.getYear(), day.getMonthValue() - 1, day.getDayOfMonth());
            }
            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Date date2 = calendar1.getTime();
            daysForRepeat.add(date2);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            holder.dayOfMonth.setText(String.valueOf(date.getDayOfMonth()));
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (date.equals(CalendarUtils.selectedDate))
            {

                holder.LinCell.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            }else {
//                holder.parentView.setBackground(defaultBackgroundDrawable);
                holder.LinCell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (date.getMonth().equals(CalendarUtils.selectedDate.getMonth())) {
                holder.dayOfMonth.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.dayOfMonth.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Event> myEvents = new ArrayList<>();


        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Event eventDB = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                eventDB = new Event(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                        CalendarUtils.stringToLocalDate(cursor.getString(3)), LocalTime.parse(cursor.getString(4)),
                        cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7));
            }

            myEvents.add(eventDB);


        }


        numEvents=0;
        numRepeatingEvents=0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            myEvents.sort((o1, o2) -> o2.getName().compareTo(o1.getName()));
        }
        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        for (int i=0; i<days.size(); i++)
        {


            List<String> eventNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Event event : myEvents) {

                if (event.getDate().equals(date) && event.getParent_id()==null) {
                    eventNames.add(event.getName());

                }
            }

            Collections.sort(eventNames);

            numEvents = eventNames.size();

            if (numEvents >= 1) {
                holder.eventDayText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventDayText.setText(eventNames.get(0));
                holder.eventDayText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventDayText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            if (numEvents >= 2) {
                holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventDayText2.setText(eventNames.get(1));
                holder.eventDayText2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventDayText2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            if (numEvents >= 3) {
                holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventDayText3.setText(eventNames.get(2));
                holder.eventDayText3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventDayText3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            if (date.toString().equals("2023-05-11"))
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
            checkForMore( holder);

        }

        cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
        for (int i=0; i<days.size(); i++) {

            List<String> eventNamesRepeating = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Event event : myEvents) {
                if (event.getDate().equals(date) && !(event.getParent_id()==null)) {
                    eventNamesRepeating.add(event.getName());
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(eventNamesRepeating);


            numRepeatingEvents = eventNamesRepeating.size();
            if (numRepeatingEvents >= 1 ) {
                holder.eventRepeatText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventRepeatText1.setText(eventNamesRepeating.get(0));
                holder.eventRepeatText1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventRepeatText1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            if (numRepeatingEvents >= 2) {
                holder.eventRepeatText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventRepeatText2.setText(eventNamesRepeating.get(1));
                holder.eventRepeatText2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventRepeatText2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            if (numRepeatingEvents >= 3) {
                holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventRepeatText3.setText(eventNamesRepeating.get(2));
                holder.eventRepeatText3.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
                holder.eventRepeatText3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
            }

            checkForMore( holder);
        }




        cursor.close();
        myDB.close();
    }
    public void checkForMore(@NonNull ViewHolder holder)
    {
        if (numEvents>=3 && numRepeatingEvents>=1)
        {
            holder.eventRepeatText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);

        }

        if (numRepeatingEvents>=3 && numEvents>1)
        {
            holder.eventDayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }

        if (numRepeatingEvents==2 && numEvents>1)
        {
            holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }

        if (numEvents==2 && numRepeatingEvents>1)
        {
            holder.eventRepeatText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);

        }

        if (numEvents>3 && numRepeatingEvents==0)
        {
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }

        if (numRepeatingEvents>3 && numEvents==0)
        {
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }
        if (numEvents>=3 && numRepeatingEvents>0)
        {
            holder.eventRepeatText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventRepeatText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }

        if (numRepeatingEvents>=3 && numEvents>0)
        {
            holder.eventDayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventDayText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.eventsMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.eventsMore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryLightTirquiso));
            holder.eventsMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
        }
    }

    // This Method returns the size of the Array
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return days.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemListener {

        void onItemClick(int position, LocalDate date);

    }

    // The ViewHolder class holds the view
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final ArrayList<LocalDate> days;
        public final View parentView;
        public final TextView dayOfMonth, eventDayText, eventDayText2, eventDayText3;
        public final TextView  eventRepeatText1, eventRepeatText2, eventRepeatText3,eventsMore;
        public final LinearLayout LinCell;


        private final OnItemListener onItemListener;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener, ArrayList<LocalDate> days) {
            super(itemView);
            parentView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
            LinCell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LinCell);
            dayOfMonth = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cellDayText);
            eventDayText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventDayText);
            eventDayText2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventDayText2);
            eventDayText3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventDayText3);
            eventRepeatText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventRepeatText1);
            eventRepeatText2= itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventRepeatText2);
            eventRepeatText3= itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventRepeatText3);
            eventsMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventsMore);


            this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.days = days;


        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            view.setSelected(true);
            onItemListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), days.get(getAdapterPosition()));

        }
    }

}
```

**daysInMonthArray**

```
public static ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonthArray() //The arraylist that month will be stored
    {
        ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonthArray = new ArrayList<>();

        YearMonth yearMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            yearMonth = YearMonth.from(selectedDate);
        }
        int daysInMonth = 0; //get how many days are in month
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            daysInMonth = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        }

        LocalDate prevMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevMonth = selectedDate.minusMonths(1);
        }
        LocalDate nextMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            nextMonth = selectedDate.plusMonths(1);
        }

        YearMonth prevYearMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevYearMonth = YearMonth.from(prevMonth);
        }
        int prevDaysInMonth = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevDaysInMonth = prevYearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        }

        LocalDate firstOfMonth = null; //get first day of month
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            firstOfMonth = CalendarUtils.selectedDate.withDayOfMonth(1);
        }
        int dayOfWeek = 0; // return int between 0-7 which is the day of the week
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            dayOfWeek = firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
            if (i <= dayOfWeek) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(prevMonth.getYear(), prevMonth.getMonth(), prevDaysInMonth + i - dayOfWeek));
                }
                if (dayOfWeek == 7 && daysInMonthArray.size() >= 7) {

                    daysInMonthArray.clear();
                }


            } else if (i > daysInMonth + dayOfWeek) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(nextMonth.getYear(), nextMonth.getMonth(), i - dayOfWeek - daysInMonth));
                }


            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(selectedDate.getYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), i - dayOfWeek));
                }

            }

        }


        return daysInMonthArray;


    }
```

**My xml is simple with the ViewPager only inside:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Don't show your whole code, give us a minimal self-contained code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: tbh is the smallest amount of code I can provide to express my problem via code..